# Display label for OOTB FormField

Tags: 2013, custom-form, form

```
<SharePoint:FormField id="ffFirstName" ControlMode="New" FieldName="Title" runat="server" />
```

This works fine but only displays the input field. Can I get it to display the form field label too?

```
Title (*):  [Input Field]
```

Also, what does the `DisableInputFieldLabel="False"` property do? It doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: where are you using this?

Comment: In a SharePoint application page

Comment: I think you need to show a bit more of your page so we know what you're doing

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a block of code in a page layout. I ususally my self add label manually to my code! but propabably you can see something in snippet gallery to show the label of your Field. Alternatively you can just add a `span`tag before the Field Snippet using your custome label!